# Count of all the object created in a java application

Tags: java

Well I know the Title is a bit misleading but I couldn't get a better one so please bear with me.

I just wanted to ask whether we can count the number of references/objects created for a particular java Application (Standalone).

I know there are profiling tools available. But my question is whether it is possible to know from code itself without having to use any third-party APIs?

Comment: What your going to do with that?

Comment: I came across this question by my collegue while having a discussion. So thought of asking.

Comment: Go through the code and count? What's the issue?

Comment: What if I want to `generalize` it.?

Comment: @Java_User Some custom jvm might be tracking reference counts at implementation level and you may be able to hook it somehow, but Java itself does not support this kind of thing.

Comment: You have one option though: Having static field in your classes that keeps track of instantiation (increment it when creating object and decrement in `finilize`) sum up them at the end. However, you won't be able to count objects that are not created by you.

Comment: Maybe go through the object tree with reflection?

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. Yes, I was thinking of `Reflection` as well. But not sure how to begin with.

Comment: @jeukku Reflection has no knowledge about allocated objects. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly count fields in a object with reflection.

Simple example:

```
private int totalobjectcount = 0;

private void count(Object o) {
    countFields(o);
    System.out.println("total object count " + totalobjectcount);
}

private void countFields(Object o) {
    totalobjectcount++;

    Class<? extends Object> c1 = o.getClass();
    countFields(o, c1);
}

private void countFields(Object o, Class<? extends Object> c1) {
    Field[] fields = c1.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        Object oo;
        field.setAccessible(true);
        oo = field.get(o);
        countFields(oo);

    }
    countFields(o, c1.getSuperclass());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Determining this from the program source code will be impossible in the general case.

1. Consider a program that might or might not loop forever (never halt).
2. Imagine that program creates different numbers of objects if it halts than if it loops forever.
3. Therefore to determine the number of objects we must determine whether the program halts.
4. But in general [that is impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)
5. Therefore there exist programs for which it is impossible to determine the number of objects created, just by examining their source code.

Comment: Thanks @Raedwald. But the profiling tools available must be doing something that gives us the head count of the objects created at any given point of time aren't they? May be I have to go throught the source of one of them.

Comment: @Java_User The profiling tools are not examining the source code. They are examining the state of an actual running program. You said "whether it is possible to know from code itself".